# Verif Receipt with perl script

Tags: perl, cordova, in-app-purchase

I have to use a perl Script to interface to verifReceipt for in App Purchase on iOS.
I use too phoneGap 1.5.0

1/ When I try to use external url it does not work.
2/ I try to use a perl script interface between phonegap html page and itunes.
I do not understand how to send data. I try this :

```
$val contains JSON object with receiptvalue and password, receiving from phonegap.

my %transformfields = (
            "receipt-data"       => $val,
            );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $req = POST($urlsend,
    Content_Type => 'application/json ; charset=UTF-8',
    Content => \%transformfields,
    #Content => $val,
    );



my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

I have always this error : 21002 java.lang.NullPointerException
I do not understand how is this possible to send data with perl script.

Comment: I'm very confused by your question. Are you using PhoneGap to hit your server and run the Perl script? I believe your first question relates to hitting an external URL in PhoneGap. If it is not working for you, check the docs on whitelisting: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: Whitelisting does not work with phonegap 1.5.0, I add itunes url, but nothing. I have to use this version.

Comment: I have to use cgi script between phonegap page, and itunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have problems with json encode and understanding how I receive data from phonegap plugins.

For help :
Phongap plugins returns transactionReceipt in Base64.
Do not encode password in Base64 too.

```
my %transformfields = ("receipt-data" => $val , "password" => $sharedsecretpass ) ;
my $jsonval = encode_json (\%transformfields);

print "Content-Type: text/html \n\n";

#my $urlsend="https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt" ;
my $urlsend="https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt" ;

my $req = POST($urlsend,
    Content_Type => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; charset=utf-8',
    Content => $jsonval,
    );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->request($req);

if ($res->is_success)
{
    #print "cgi Content : " . $res->content . "<br />\n";
    my $retour = decode_json( $res->content );
    if ($retour->{'status'} eq "0")
    {
            print "--OK--<br />\n";
            print $retour->{receipt}->{product_id} . "<br />";
            print $retour->{receipt}->{transaction_id} . "<br />";
            print $retour->{receipt}->{purchase_date} . "<br />";
            print $retour->{receipt}->{expires_date} . "<br />";

            #$res->content
    }
```